# Make Level-2 Landsat images comparable with Level-2A Sentinel-2 images

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction

Is there a way to make Level-2 Landsat images (e.g. Landsat-5 images ordered from EarthExplorer) comparable with Level-2A Sentinel-2 images?

The objective is to calculate water or vegetation indices (NDVI or NDWI) from both and be able to accurately evaluate the change between the two, since they were not acquired on the same year obviously. The Sentinel-2 Level-2A images were either downloaded from Sentinel Hub or atmospherically corrected with Sen2cor.

While both of them are atmospherically corrected, the pixels values I find in their image bands are on a completely different order of magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the LS4-7 level 2 surface reflectance products which are supplied as Int16, you need to multiply the values by the scale factor 0.0001 to convert the values to 0.0-1.0.  This is documented in the [product guide](https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-4-7-surface-reflectance-code-ledaps-product-guide).

Comment: However this is not the only problem! Check out the Harmonized Landsat Sentinel-2 (HLS) project as an example to see what kind of processing you would potentially need to do. There various approaches that you can find online apart from HLS, though. Good Luck!